# Are questions about tar off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

Are questions about software tools (like tar) no longer on-topic on Stack Overflow? I have been using Stack Overflow for over 10 years now and I can't remember a time when questions about software tools used during software development were considered off-topic. Currently there are over 2500 questions tagged with[tar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tar).

But today my question "What is the list of tar archive suffixes?" was deleted by a moderator from Stack Overflow. Here is the link to the deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73771378/ (not sure if you can see deleted questions).

The reason for deleting says:

> This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers.

But `tar` is used by programmers while packaging software development artifacts. Is a question about `tar` still not a good fit for Stack Overflow?

I am not worried that the question was deleted. I would just like to know where the line is between what is considered tools primarily used by programmers and what isn't. If I can understand where this line is it will help me to post questions more judiciously in future.

Comment: Tar isn't a tool primarily for programmers.

Comment: "*But tar is used by programmers while packaging software development artifacts.*" programmers [may also be working on a boat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) but so what?

Comment: Notwithstanding whether `tar`-the-program is a programming related problem, in how far is *the list of tar archive suffixes* a programming related problem?

Comment: @Dharman: How many non-programmers (and non-coders in general) do you know who use command line utilities like `tar`? And how many coders do you know who use such command line utilities?

Comment: @user000001 power users, system admins, support people.

Comment: @VLAZ That is not a number

Comment: @user000001 OK, then 42. Why does a number matter here?

Comment: @VLAZ: 42 coders and how many non-coders? Of course it matters, I know nobody, and I assert that almost no one uses linux command line tools with no coding experience whatsoever.

Comment: @LoneLearner: But you will have better luck getting answers to such questions on the sister site [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: @user000001 we don't classify users by what they have in their background. My mom has covered a bit of Fortran in university. That doesn't make her "a coder" as she hasn't really used that knowledge at all since. If she does or doesn't use a tool, her coding experience doesn't make what she asks about on-topic or not. The fact is that there are large groups of users that aren't primarily coders who can and would use command line tools for non-programming purposes. I've been using CLI since before I wrote I single line of code. `ping` doesn't change its topicality after I started coding.

Comment: @VLAZ: So 42 vs 1 :)

Comment: @user000001 1. You didn't verify what 42 refers to. When I said 42 I was referring  to the number of non-coders. Because you asked me for a number related to, and I quote: " power users, system admins, support people". Which itself was in the context of "How many non-programmers (and non-coders in general)". I don't know how or why you decided that it refers to coders given the context. Nor do I see why it matters what figure I give you because:

Comment: @user000001 2. Seems you're looking to dismiss an argument based on a logical fallacy. I don't have to give you accurate number of people *I know* that will validate the claim that command line tools are not only used for programming purpose. Failure to provide a satisfactory number does not mean that the opposite argument is true.

Comment: Claiming the argument hasn't been won does not mean it hasn't been.

Comment: @VLAZ: Even you said in your comment: *"... users that aren't **primarily** coders who can and would use command line tools ..."*. So you kind of validated my point.

Comment: on a more serious note, if the need for this information was programming related (aka if you explained *why* you needed this information and what problem you were trying to solve by obtaining it) it likely would have stayed open... as then you'd be putting more focus on the programming problem you are solving, rather than the features/history of a tool.

Comment: @user000001 you're not making any sense. Your point was that *only* coders use command line tools. I said the opposite with by users who "users that **aren't** primarily coders". Not being primarily a coder doesn't imply they are all coders. The same way saying "The animals in the zoo are mostly not dogs" - doesn't mean that they are all some variation of dogs. Some would be (e.g., dingoes), some would be partially dog (e.g., wolves), others will have no relation at all (e.g., giraffes). You can't make the claim that zoos are for dogs based on this sentence alone.

Comment: *programmers may also be working on a boat but so what?* Did a lot of code for boats over the years.

Comment: @user4581301 *on* a boat. As in physically occupying the same X and Y coordinates as where a boat is located. Not *for* a boat.

Comment: Did a lot of the code for the boats on the boats. Did a lot more debugging of code, mind you. Sea trials are groovy.

Answer (score 11):

Let's look at the [top ten questions from 2021<sup>1</sup>, by score, in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5btar%5d%20created%3a1y%20is%3aquestion):

[TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE and TAR_ENTRY_INVALID when trying to npm install any package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200957/) (1)

[Error: docker buildx on x86_64 for building multiarch--x86_64, arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272380/) (1)

[Disable Chrome's gzip automatic decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68112512/) (2)

[What is the fundamental difference between tar (Unix) and tarfile (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585800/) (3)

[Remove duplicates from tar archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686791/) (4)

[AWS lambda tar file extraction doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884502/) (4)

[How do I extract a tar file in nodejs using the pipeline() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661737/) (4)

[How to dump in memorry files to an in memmory tar and than dump that tar to disk in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442775/) (4)

[Can't map a function to tarfile members in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67047533/) (4)

[How decompress and unpack tar.gz archive in download process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966292/) (4)

The numbers beside the links are my categorization:

Group 1: "I tried to install a development tool or otherwise set up a programming environment, using an installation process that involves extracting a `tar` archive; what went wrong?"

Group 2: "I have some Javascript code that is supposed to download compressed data, but on some browsers it decompresses automatically, which I don't want; how do I prevent it?"

Group 3: "Why do these two `tar` archives representing the same content have different file sizes?" (i.e., a conceptual question about the file format itself, being asked in order to verify that the code is working properly, or possibly to look for opportunities to conserve disk space... ?)

Group 4: "How can I manipulate/extract the contents of a `tar` archive in a specific using actual code (in bash, Python etc.)?" (or debugging questions related to this, e.g. a failure of an AWS setup to extract the archive automatically)

Do you see the pattern? These are all technical questions about *how to use* `tar`, in a programming context, to *solve a practical problem* that matters to programmers.

Having a list of file extensions doesn't represent such a problem. You **might** be able to frame it as one - for example, if you said that you were writing a Bash script that automatically "does something" with every file in a directory, depending on its type, and the "something" includes extraction for tarfiles. (Even then - while Bash is a programming language and writing Bash scripts is definitely on topic for Stack Overflow - you would *probably* get *better* help at [unix.se].)

However, this would be a massive XY problem. The question isn't really "what suffixes are there?", but instead "how can I tell if a given file is a tar file?". The thing is - there isn't an exhaustive list, because `tar` comes from the Unix ecosystem, where *filename extensions are not expected to determine the type of a file*. Any time you see `foo.tar.gz`, that is people following a convention to communicate information on a human level - a convention that comes from the DOS world. (At some point, of course, everyone stopped caring about limiting those extensions to three letters, but that doesn't change the history.)

Also note here that "list" questions generally don't do very well. To justify "what are all the Xs?", it needs to be demonstrable that X is a closed set; it has to be able to solve a practical problem to have that information; and it should be that an explicit list of Xs is for some reason more useful than a simple **rule that tells you** whether or not something is an X.

---

> I have been using Stack Overflow for over 10 years now and I can't remember a time when questions about software tools used during software development were considered off-topic.

It comes across that you might be wondering if the policy has *changed* over time. I don't think it's the case that questions about `tar` have become inherently more or less likely to be deemed on topic over the years.

My evidence: As you note, there are over 2500 questions in the tag - I [currently see](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btar%5D+is%3Aquestion) 2576, of which 2438 are not closed. In the above search for questions from 2021, I see 193 results, of which 186 are not closed. Stack Overflow has been around for about 14 years, so it seems to me that `tar` questions are being asked at around the usual pace; and if anything they are *more* accepted now than usual (96% vs 95%, although this result seems very unlikely to be statistically significant).

[1] That was what was easy to search for. Searching for questions in 2022 wouldn't be fair since the year isn't over yet.

Comment: Dotted file extensions was around in Multics then Unix as informal typing.

Answer (score 7):

> I would just like to know where the line is between what is considered
> tools primarily used by programmers and what isn't

What is said in the help center.

> software tools commonly used by programmers; **and** is a practical,
> answerable problem that is unique to software development

Emphasis mine. Nice and ambiguous as it is left up to your own interpretation what "tools commonly used by programmers" exactly means, you can argue that tar fits the bill.

But that is why that extra addendum also exists; it has to be a problem unique to software development. At that point tar no longer fits the description.

That last bit about software development is where you can still see head butting going on. Let's take an example of setting a font in an IDE. Not a "programming problem". Except that it is done in an IDE, which is a tool primarily used for software development purposes. So are such questions allowed or not? In the interest of not having to argue about it all the time and see inconsistent handling of such questions, the wish seems to be to just let all questions about tools primarily used for software development purposes be on-topic.

Tar is not such a tool.